# Count elements of array A in array B with Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have two arrays of strings, say

```
A = ('abc', 'joia', 'abas8', '09ma09', 'oiam0')
```

and

```
B = ('gfdg', '89jkjj', '09ma09', 'asda', '45645ghf', 'dgfdg', 'yui345gd', '6456ds', '456dfs3', 'abas8', 'sfgds').
```

What I want to do is simply to count the number of elements of every string in A that appears in B (if any). For example, the resulted array here should be: `C = (0, 0, 1, 1, 0)`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it how idursun suggested, it will work, but may be not efficient as if you'll prepare intersection first. If B is much bigger than A it will give massive speedup. 'intersect' method has better 'big-O' complexity then doing linear search for each element of A in B.

```
  val A = Array("abc", "joia", "abas8", "09ma09", "oiam0") 
  val B = Array("gfdg", "89jkjj", "09ma09", "asda", "45645ghf", "dgfdg", "yui345gd", "6456ds", "456dfs3", "abas8", "sfgds")

  val intersectCounts: Map[String, Int] =
    A.intersect(B).map(s => s -> B.count(_ == s)).toMap

  val count = A.map(intersectCounts.getOrElse(_, 0))

  println(count.toSeq)
```

Result

```
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think you need `intersect` and `toMap`. Just `val intersectCounts = B.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)` should do the job. It's a bit faster too (still O(n+m), but less overhead).

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
A.map( x => B.count(y => y == x)))
```

Comment: I like this one better than my solution that uses foldLeft

Answer (score 0):

Use a foldLeft construction as the yield off of each element of A:

```
  val A = List("a","b")
  val B = List("b","b")

  val C = for (a <- A) 
          yield B.foldLeft(0) { case (totalc : Int, w : String) =>
      totalc + (if (w == a) 1 else 0)
    }
```

And the result:

```
C: List[Int] = List(0, 2)
```